# Выделение области вершин мышью GraphStream

Tags: java, swing

Есть `JFrame` внутри которого расположен `JButton` и `SingleGraph`. На viewer'e графа стоит AutoLayout. Поскольку не нашёл среди стандартных методов выделения, для viewer'a реализовал слушателя согласно [гайду](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/). Переопределил методы зажатия:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x1 = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        y1 = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        //vpipe.pump();
        //System.out.println("Pump it!");
    }
```

И отпускания мыши:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        x2 = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        y2 = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        Collection<GraphicElement> selected = vw.allNodesOrSpritesIn(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        selected.forEach((c)->c.setAttribute("ui.label","Selected"));
        vpipe.pump();
    }
```

Но при этом метки не устанавливаются, не могу понять в чём проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` возвращает абсолютную позицию, а `allNodesOrSpritesIn(x1,y1,x2,y2)` относительную. Решением является получение относительной позиции курсора от `MouseEvent` через `getX()` и `getY()`.